# How to get back to the command line after launching a Node.js script?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, terminal

I'm on a Mac OS X 10.6.7.

I started a `node.js` script, which starts an HTTP server.

The problem is that I lost the command line, it looks like this:

```
$me cd directory
$me node test.js
Message from test.js: Server is running on localhost
..|
```

| = indicates the caret

It's possible to write but I'm unable to run any code, it's like writing a plain string, how can I get back to the commmand line?

*Sorry I'm really noob in terminal :)*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to terminate the program and get back to the shell prompt.

If you want a program to run in the background and return you to a shell prompt, append an ampersand (`&`) to the end of the command.  For example:

```
node test.js &
```

Comment: If you want to keep it running press [ctrl] + [z] then type __bg__

Comment: Thanks @ChrisNava I never knew that you could do `bg` and `fg` without using %1 (or %something). Great point!

Answer (score 3):

Just open a new tab by pressing `Cmd-T`, or a new window (using `Cmd-N`). You want to get warning/error messages that program sends to your terminal.

---

You can also use `screen` to get multiple... er... terminals in a single tab/window.

Press `Ctrl-A Ctrl-C` to *create* a new terminal, `Ctrl-A Ctrl-N` or `Ctrl-A Ctrl-P` (repeatedly) to go to the next and previous terminals. Type `exit` in all `screen` terminals to leave.

---

Regarding `node`: Check the documentation -- it should be possible to start it as a background server.

Answer (score -1):

Just type <kbd>Q</kbd> to get back to the command line, from the help module.

Answer (score -2):

To exit, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (twice) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or type `.exit`.

Comment: Avoid posting answers to old questions that already have well received answers unless you have something substantial and new to add.